# Prisma find element on one to many relation where array of ids are assign to element

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, prisma

I have prisma schema

```
model StoryHashtag {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title   String
  stories Story[]
}

model Story {
  id            String         @id @default(uuid())
  hashtags      StoryHashtag[]
  title         String
}
```

and in the database I have couple of records

story:
1 "this element would like to receive"
2 "this element dont wont to reveive"
3 "this element dont wont to reveive"

hashtags
1 hashtag1
2 hashtag2
3 hashtag3

StoryHashtag
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
3 2

and I would like to write where in prisma where would like it to return those items that meet the condition in each case.
so if I want to search for stories that have hashtag1 and also hastag2 so only story with id 1 will get.

So the request from frontend look like: give me a story where they have hashtags (AND)
hashtags: [1,2] but if story 1 has other hashtags it's ok. I only care to have these hashtags which is necessary.

I tried with:

```
{ hashtags: { every: { AND: storyHashtagIds.map((id: number) => ({ id })) } } }
```

But I got nothing.

I kind of do it by javascript to get every story which has 1 or 2 hastaghs so in these example all elements got to js and map hashtags to story so it will

```
{
 1: [1,2,3],
 2: [1],
 3: [2], 
}
```

and check every element

```
let array1 = [1,2],
    array2 = [1,2,3],
    array3 = [1];

let checker = (arr, target) => target.every(v => arr.includes(v));

console.log(checker(array2, array1));  // true
console.log(checker(array3, array1));  // false
```

But I would like to know if I can do it in prisma or in native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to put couple of statements you need to push to where

```
   if (storyHashtagIds && storyHashtagIds.length > 0) {
      storyHashtagIds.forEach((id) => {
        whereBuilder.push({ hashtags: { some: { id } } })
      })
    }
```

instead of

```
{ hashtags: { every: { AND: storyHashtagIds.map((id: number) => ({ id })) } } }
```